# Unable to use Spring Property Placeholders in logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I have a Spring Boot console app using Logback. All of the properties (for the app as well as for Logback) are externalized into a standard application.properties file in the classpath. These properties are picked up just fine in the app itself, but are not picked up in the logback.xml file. It appears as though the logback.xml is processed before Spring Boot fires up, therefore the EL placeholders are not processed.

Using the FileNamePattern as an example, in the application.properties, I have something like this:

```
log.filePattern=/%d{yyyy/MM-MMMM/dd-EEEE}
```

and in logback.xml, I'll have this:

```xml
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>${log.logDirectory}${log.filePattern}.log
    </FileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
```

When running the app, I'll see errors such as:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:25 - 
RuntimeException in Action for tag [rollingPolicy]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FileNamePattern
[log.logDirectory_IS_UNDEFINEDlog.filePattern_IS_UNDEFINED.log]
does not contain a valid DateToken
```

Similar code works just fine in other Spring (not Spring Boot) apps, so I'm curious if Spring Boot just behaves a bit differently.

## Solution:

Thanks for the reply @Gary! Good to know about the difference between Spring EL and Logback's variables...I had assumed it was Spring that was in charge of parsing those variables for me. I **did** have the  element, but that got me to thinking.

My application.properties file was outside of the jar, so Logback had no idea where to find it. By keeping my Spring-related properties in my external application.properties file, moving the logging-related properties into an application-internal.properties file (located **inside** the jar), and pointing Logback to **that** file (`<property resource="application-internal.properties" />`) got everything working as expected!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`${...}` is not "Spring EL" in Spring; they are property placeholders.

I think you are confusing logback "variables" with Spring "Property Placeholders".

They just happen to use the same syntax `${...}`.

logback knows nothing about the Spring property placeholder mechanism and vice-versa. You need to configure your logback variables according to the logback documentation and not in `application.properties` / `application.yml` which is strictly a Spring (boot) concept.

**EDIT:**

After a quick look at the logback docs, adding

```xml
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

to the `logback.xml` should work.

Comment: Here's the link to said "logback docs": http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution

Comment: @Gary I want configurable file pattern extension. is this possible? or I want to override internal logback.xml with external logback.xml. is this possible?

Comment: For an external file (not in the classpath, but available on the filesystem):
<property file="environment.properties" />

Comment: THANK YOU for the missing voodoo (the property resource thing).  FYI:  "application.yml" will also work... as I document here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186668/spring-boot-logback-db-appender-properties/54288986#54288986

Answer (score 89):

Since Spring Boot 1.3 you have a better way of getting spring properties into your logback-spring.xml configuration:

Now you can just add a "springProperty" element.
The attribute *name* refers to the logback property and the attribute *source* refers to the spring property

```xml
<springProperty name="destination" source="my.loggger.extradest"/>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${destination}</file>
        ...
    </file>
</appender>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/055ace37f006120b0006956b03c7f358d5f3729f

edit: thanks to Anders

.........

Comment: is there a logback-spring.groovy equivalent to that ^^?

Comment: where is the DOC for this thing ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: @MatthewPayne did you ever find how to do this in groovy

Comment: This is not a fool proof solution. If you externalize your logback-spring.xml file by including an external file and then change , sya, "maxSize" to 2KB from 100MB, you will see the files getting created as destination_IS_UNDEFINED.log. That's because as @Gary Russell has explained in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

As answered above you can access the spring boot properties using the `<springProperty>` element...but a thing to keep in mind is that the logback configuration file must be named `logback-spring.xml`, it doesn't work if you name the file `logback.xml` (I'm using `spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE`)

Comment: Works for me using `logback-dev.xml` and `logback-prod.xml` with `spring-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE`

Comment: If still not work, check app config name it should be application.properties, or whatever name you specified to your app. Additional @PropertySource-es seems to be not working in this case

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind: at least for me, it didn't work until I renamed `application.properties` to `bootstrap.properties`

Answer (score 2):

The solutions above work mostly for `bootrap.properties`. However, the only way to use properties from remote Spring Config Server in logback config I've currently found, is to apply them programatically:

```
@Component
public class LoggerConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent> {

    @Autowired protected Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
        // enviroment here has already loaded all properties and you may alter logback config programatically
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger rootLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    }


}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215011/320761) is a good example how to customize logback with new appender this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to map Spring properties to Logback properties and use them in the Conditions:

```
logback-spring.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="ACTIVE_PROFILE" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
<!--   defined in the application-prod.properties/>-->
<springProperty scope="context" name="SPRING_WRITER_DISABLED" source="writer.disabled"/>
<property name="LOGBACK_WRITER_DISABLED" value="${SPRING_WRITER_DISABLED}"/>

<if condition='property("LOGBACK_WRITER_DISABLED").equals("false")'>
    <then>
        <appender name="testappender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${ACTIVE_PROFILE}/${HOSTNAME}/testappender.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>
                    {ACTIVE_PROFILE}/${HOSTNAME}/testappender-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
                <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <logger name="testappender" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="testappender"/>
        </logger>
    </then>
</if>
</configuration>
```