# Logback and Spring Boot's new springProperty lookup mechanism not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RC1 through spring-cloud Brixton.M2 and have been unable to pull spring boot properties into logback.xml as implied by this feature checkin [Support springProperty in logback configurations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/055ace37f006120b0006956b03c7f358d5f3729f)

I'm using .yml files and want to pull application name out of bootstrap.yml or application.yml.

logback-spring.xml:

```
<configuration>
      <springProperty scope="context" name="myappName" source="spring.application.name"/>
      <contextName>${myappName}</contextName>
      <appender name="logFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <file>logs/${myappName}.log</file>
         ... 
      </appender>
      ...
</configuration>
```

The documentation here [Spring Boot Logback extensions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#environment-properties) doesn't help much.

This other stackoverflow question [Unable to use Spring Property Placeholders in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322709/unable-to-use-spring-property-placeholders-in-logback-xml) is older and doesnt work for me either.   Any insight would be helpful.

Per request, here is the relevant dependency tree that is being used

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
```

Per 2nd request for info, what is actually going on is that logback property *myappName* does not get a value.  The way I know this is that the value becomes "myappName_IS_UNDEFINED" and my logfile gets named "myappName_IS_UNDEFINED.log" and the %contextName is set to "myappName_IS_UNDEFINED".

Comment: You'll need to at least include your build control file (Maven or Gradle).

Comment: Nowadays, you should validate  Nikita Khomenko's reply instead of the actual one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To provide my analysis and a solution for future readers...    I tried with `spring.application.name` values in `bootstrap.yml`, then `application.yml`, then `application.properties` but none worked.  I thought it was because I used `logback.xml`, but converting to `logback-spring.xml` resulted in no change. Looking at the code committed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/055ace37f006120b0006956b03c7f358d5f3729f), pulling the values via `this.environment.getProperty(source)` is dependent on when the property sources are loaded vs when the `logback-spring.xml` file is interpreted.  Not sure why Dave Syer was able to get it to work but my .xml variable was populated before local property sources are added to the environment.

The value *is* populated within the .xml file if I set it via SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties().  Hence that is the route I took.

- Built a SpringApplicationRunListener
- In `SpringApplicationRunListener.started()`, I read in bootstrap.yml (where I required spring.application.name for all framework users) via `new ClassPathResource("/bootstrap.yml")`
- Set a new property, `service.log.name` in a HashMap based off the value
- Called `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties()` with that HashMap
- Then I was able to use `${myappName}` within the `logback-spring.xml` file

I admit this is not a perfect solution, but one that works for now and will likely continue to work for future releases of springBoot.  I am open to further ideas but wanted to provide a solution that worked for others that are having the same experience.

Comment: cause it is too early that spring has not make the Environment ready.

Comment: if you load your own properties why wouldn't you just add it to argument in form of `--property＝value`? this should be priorer then default property source and simple.

Answer (score 10):

Our solution is to rename `logback(-spring).xml` to e.g. `logback-delayed.xml` so that it won't be read before Spring Cloud Config, and then activate it later explicitly from the config file in the Cloud Config repo, e.g.:

```
logging:
    config: classpath:logback-delayed.xml
    prop-to-fill-in-logback-delayed.xml: whatever
```

Declaring the variable in logback-delayed.xml

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="localName" source="prop-to-fill-in-logback-delayed.xml"/>
```

Using the variable in logback-delayed.xml

```
<file>${localName}.log</file>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add this to your logback file:

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Spring Boot 1.3.1 and I was facing the same issue.

What I finally found out was that the property must be set in BOTH application.yml AND bootstrap.yml. Setting it in just one or the other does not work. Passing it only as a -D argument does also work.

It's a bit of a hazzle to have a double configuration though, especially when it is configured per profile as well.

Maybe the logback configuration is needed in both phases and the property value does not carry over.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, your logback configuration file name should be suffixed with `-spring`, no matter the file is in `xml` or `groovy` format.

in spring, config center is preferred, then command line arguments, then local properties in `bootstrap.yml` and all local property files.

if there are many properties in multiple configuration files the first will effect no matter what value it is.

by the way, please make sure there are no programmatically logback settings before `EnvironmentPrepared` event cause the logback settings will be reset. meanwhile, if there are multiple spring contexts the logback settings will be reset several times for each context.

please check these rules and make sure every step is in control.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the spring app name , you must first defined the spring property in logback-spring.xml as shown below :

`<springProperty scope="context" name="MyApp" source="com.app.star"/>`

So If you are accessing the source above then logically it must be defined in application.yml file as below :

`com:
  app:
    star: HelloWorld`

`# Logging Configurations
logging:
  config: "classpath:logback-spring.xml"`

Now in logback-spring.xml, the appName would be set with name as 'HelloWorld' which you can access with `{MyApp}`.

Hope the above explanation would help.

Comment: any idea how do you do this in logback-spring.groovy?

Comment: he always had the property, it did not work for him

Comment: and if you are using spring boot - you dont have to specify logging.config

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I put the "spring.application.name" in "application.properties" (not "bootstrap.properties" because the logging system is initialized in a phase where the bootstrap properties are not yet available I believe). I don't think logback will let you set the "context" name either but YMMV.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.  Using spring-boot 1.3.0.RC1 and logback 1.1.3.  Tried application.properties in /resources and in root directory.  Works if I do straight logback properties using this `<property name="myappName" value="configeurekaclient"/>`.   The contextName setting doesn't work half the time, I keep getting (http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-801) problem.   So still something fishy.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question with more details of what actually goes wrong?

Comment: It works for me if I put the value in "application.properties", but not "application.yml".  Are yaml files processed at a later point then property files?  I'm using spring-boot 1.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it only worked using a command line property, like --property.value=asd.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I have updated only in bootstrap.properties. Updates in application.properties does not work and also not needed.

```
kafka.host.name=xxxxx
kafka.host.port=9092
```

In Logback.xml

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="kafkaHostName" source="kafka.host.name" />
```

`<springProperty scope="context" name="kafkaHostPort" source="kafka.host.port"` />

```
  <appender name="asyncXSPKafkaAppender" class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.KafkaAppender">
        <encoder class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.encoding.LayoutKafkaMessageEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
        <topic>logstash_logs</topic>
        <keyingStrategy class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.keying.RoundRobinKeyingStrategy" />
        <deliveryStrategy class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.delivery.AsynchronousDeliveryStrategy" />
        <producerConfig>bootstrap.servers=**${kafkaHostName}:${kafkaHostPort}**</producerConfig>
        <producerConfig>retries=2</producerConfig>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by moving the properties I needed from `application.properties` to `bootstrap.properties`