# AWS Cloudwatch Logback Appender for Spring Boot Applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to send Logs directly to Cloudwatch from my Spring Boot Application.
The [Logback Appender I'm using](https://github.com/pierredavidbelanger/logback-awslogs-appender), of course needs AWS Credentials.
Since most developers doesn't have AWS Credentials on their local machines and just want to log into a file according to the the logback-spring.xml configuration.
Most tests fail locally, because of missing aws credentials.
Is there a way to initialize the logback appender only for a specific profile?
Here's a snapshot of the logback-spring.xml:

```
<!--  Configuration for your local environment -->
<springProfile name="${user.name}">
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

<appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
</appender>


<!-- Configuration for Development Environment --> 
<springProfile name="dev">
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="AWS_LOGS_DEV" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

<appender name="AWS_LOGS_DEV" class="ca.pjer.logback.AwsLogsAppender">
    <layout>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </layout>
    <logGroupName>/dev</logGroupName>
    <logStreamName>log_${date}</logStreamName>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already solved. You just need to extract the appender to another logback-file:

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<!--  Configuration for your local environment -->
<springProfile name="${user.name}">
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

<appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
</appender>


<!-- Configuration for Environment in AWS, extracted into its own logback-prod.xml file--> 
<springProfile name="prod">
    <include resource="logback-prod.xml" />
</springProfile>
```

**logback-prod.xml**

```
<included>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="AWS_LOGS_DEV" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE" />
    </root>
    
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>
    <appender name="AWS_LOGS_DEV" class="ca.pjer.logback.AwsLogsAppender">
        <layout>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </layout>
        <logGroupName>/prod</logGroupName>
        <logStreamName>log_${date}</logStreamName>
        <maxBatchLogEvents>200</maxBatchLogEvents>
        <maxFlushTimeMillis>30000</maxFlushTimeMillis>
        <maxBlockTimeMillis>5000</maxBlockTimeMillis>
    </appender>
</included>
```

Comment: Where can I find all the possible options like ${date} that could be used in logback configuration?

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk I think this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322709/unable-to-use-spring-property-placeholders-in-logback-xml