# Externalize loglevel in logback xml in a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I would like to externalize the log level in `logback-spring.xml` as below,

```xml
<root level="${logback.loglevel}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

In my `application.yml` file I have:

```yaml
logback:
    loglevel: WARN
```

But this value is not picked from Logback XML and runs with `DEBUG` level instead. If I hard coded the value there as `WARN` only it runs as `WARN` level.

Comment: Unless you have environment specific config, I would advise over-riding  log level  `<root level="${logback.loglevel:-INFO}">` using system property of each enviroment/runtime as `-Dlogback.loglevel=DEBUG`. Default INFO if system property passed then DEBUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the type of configuration externalization you are trying to achieve is based on the Spring `application.yml` configuration files.

If that is the case, [Spring Boot provides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.log-levels) out of the box different configuration properties you can use to define the appropriate logging level, no matter the underlying logging library implementation you are using.

You can provide the appropriate configuration in your different `application.properties` or `application.yaml`, something like:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: "warn"
    org.springframework.web: "debug"
    org.hibernate: "error"
```

Be aware that using a custom `logback-spring.xml` file is unnecessary.

Please, consider review the aforementioned [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.log-levels) if you need more information.

Comment: ok that means i could remove logback-spring.xml and add above in application.yml and things would work know?

Comment: Yes @Harshana. Unless you require a special behavior, something not provided by default by Spring or something special only provided by logback, there is no need to use `logback-spring.xml`: as you can see in the documentation I cited, Spring Boot provides different properties you can use to customize how logging should behave without any additional configuration. You only need to include the mentioned properties in your application.yaml file and the log levels should be appropriate to the one you indicate in that file.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is just changing log level, then should follow the approach in jccampanero's answer. That is provided by Spring boot out of the box to make things simple for developers.

However, if you want to do more customization on the logging, and you want to  have the flexibility to pass config values from `application.properties` or `application.yml` to your `logback-spring.xml`. It is also very simple.

For example in `application.properties` you have this config `my.logging.level=WARN`
In your `logback-spring.xml` you can simply retrieve it by this

```xml
<springProperty scope="context" name="logLevel" source="my.logging.level" defaultValue="INFO"/>
```

And now you can use `logLevel` (as defined in the springProperty tag above) in your `logback-spring.xml` file like this:

```xml
<root level="${loglevel}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *springProfiles* for that. An example `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <springProfile name="production">
        <root level="warn">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="default,local,develop,qa">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

The resources folder:

[image]

Whether you start `spring` in `production` or either (`default, local, develop, qa`) it will use the right log level.

Starting the application with the arguments `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production` will set the log-level to `warn`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also externalize the logback log level like this: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly

> You may define properties dynamically using the  element. The define element takes two mandatory attributes: name and class. The name attribute designates the name of the property to set whereas the class attribute designates any class implementing the PropertyDefiner interface.

For example with a configuration file like this:

```
<configuration>

  <define name="rootLevel" class="a.class.implementing.PropertyDefiner"/>

  <root level="${rootLevel}"/>
</configuration>
```

And your `a.class.implementing.PropertyDefiner` could look like this:

```
package a.class.implementing;

import ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase;

public class PropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {
    @Override
    public String getPropertyValue() {
        // todo: retrieve the property from your application context
        return "WARN";
    }
}
```

With this setup you can have any system wide available property at runtime define the loglevel.

Answer (score 0):

[Unable to use Spring Property Placeholders in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322709/unable-to-use-spring-property-placeholders-in-logback-xml)

> Good to know about the difference between Spring EL and Logback's
> variables...I had assumed it was Spring that was in charge of parsing
> those variables for me. I did have the element, but that got me to
> thinking.
>
> My `application.properties` file was outside of the jar, so Logback had
> no idea where to find it. By keeping my Spring-related properties in
> my external `application.properties` file, moving the logging-related
> properties into an `application-internal.properties` file (located
> inside the jar), and pointing Logback to that file () got everything working
> as expected!