# multiple logback.xml configuration files for different tomcat war applications

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, war, logback

I'm dealing with 2 WAR  applications (let's call them app1.war and app2.war) deployed in a tomcat7 environment. 
Through the setenv.sh I'm extending the classpath to a shared folder located in /opt/configurations.

I'd like to structure my configurations this way:

`configurations/
├── app1.properties
├── app2.properties
├── logback-app1.xml
└── logback-app2.xml`

How do I tell to each application to read different logback*.xml files from the shared classpath? In other words, how do I tell app1.war to read only logback-app1.xml and app2.war to read only logback-app2.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this question here : http://vtanase.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-create-different-logback.html

The point is to use a different JNDI entry declared in each web.xml

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>logback/configuration-resource</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>app1/logback.xml</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

and add a property for logback to look JNDI :

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI"
```

If the problem was to separate the resulting logging file for each war, there is an other way to achieve this with one single logback.xml using SiftingAppender.
Examples can be found :

- [Multiple WARs sharing the same logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864271/multiple-wars-sharing-the-same-logback-xml)
- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/siftingappender-logging-different-threads-to-different-log-files.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this with annotations?

Comment: I don't know a way to configure it with annotations, but if you want to get rid of the web.xml, you can try the java config, there is an exemple here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910955/programmatically-configure-logback-appender .