# Multiple WARs sharing the same logback.xml

Tags: war, logback

Is the following logback setup safe and good practice.

I have Multiple WARs (deployed WebSphere 8.5.5) and want them to share a single `logback.xml`

`-Dlogback.configurationFile=/opt/logback.xml -Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI`

The `logback.xml` uses a [`SiftingAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/sift/SiftingAppender.html) with [`JNDIBasedContextDiscriminator`](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/sift/JNDIBasedContextDiscriminator.html) so each WAR gets its own log file.

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.JNDIBasedContextDiscriminator">
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${contextName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>/var/log/${contextName}.log</file>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-50(%level %logger{35}) cn=%contextName - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

Each WAR `web.xml` will have `contextName`:

```
<env-entry>
  <description>JNDI logging context for this app</description>
  <env-entry-name>logback/context-name</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>ContextNameWebAppA</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if using the Jndi discriminator is safe or a good practice, but
it seems to be the way Logback solves this issue : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html
They indicate that the performance can be better in adding this to your configuration :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.servlet.LoggerContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>LoggerContextFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

On an other hand, I can share what I'm trying to do to avoid setting the system properties `logback.ContextSelector=JNDI`.

I use instead the `MDCBasedDiscriminator` which will get the discriminating value defined with `MDC.put(key,value)`.
The MDC map is available as a thread local variable, so it must be set for every thread initiated by the web server.
For this initialisation I used a `javax.servlet.Filter` placed before other filters, this filter will put the correct value in MDC.

I don't think this is better than what you did, but it's an alternative to the JNDI property, the problem is that the shutting down log are in the `unknown.log`.

Here is some code :

```
public class WarLoggingFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String WAR_NAME_ATTRIBUTE = "WAR_NAME";
    private String warName;

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        warName = filterConfig.getInitParameter(WAR_NAME_ATTRIBUTE);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        insertIntoMDC(warName);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void clearMDC() {
        MDC.remove(WAR_NAME_ATTRIBUTE);
    }

    private static void insertIntoMDC(final String warName) {
        MDC.put(WAR_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, warName);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        clearMDC();
    }


    /**
     * Register this filter in the servlet context. Adds the necessary init
     * parameter.
     *
     * @param warName
     * @param servletContext
     */
    public static void registerMe(final String warName, final ServletContext servletContext) {
        // MDC for the startup thread
        insertIntoMDC(warName);
        // MCD for next threads
        final Dynamic addFilter = servletContext.addFilter(warName, WarLoggingFilter.class);
        addFilter.setInitParameter(WarLoggingFilter.WAR_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, warName);
        addFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    }

}
```

And the logback file :

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
            <key>WAR_NAME</key>
            <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${WAR_NAME}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>/tmp/${WAR_NAME}.log</file>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{30}\(%line\) - %message%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
```

And the registration can be for example in a spring security initializer :

```
public class MySecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    /**
     * Invoked before the springSecurityFilterChain is added.
     *
     * @param servletContext
     *            the {@link ServletContext}
     */
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        // Tell logback to log this web app events in a separate file
        WarLoggingFilter.registerMe("my_webapp", servletContext);
    }
```