# How to disable Logback output to console programmatically but append to file

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have setup Logback file appender programmatically and set log level into `ALL`.
The reason was to set log level `ALL` i wanted to log file contains all log details like`(INFO,DEBUG,WARN and etc...)`But i want to avoid those details  from the console.If anyone knows please let me know how can i disable Logback output to console programmatically.

**Logger code snippet**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910955/programmatically-configure-logback-appender)

```
private static Logger createLoggerFor(String string, String file) {
          LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
          PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();

          ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n");
          ple.setContext(lc);
          ple.start();
          FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
          fileAppender.setFile(file);
          fileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
          fileAppender.setContext(lc);
          fileAppender.start();

          Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);
          logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
          logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
          logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */

          return logger;
    }
```

**Note**:When i set log level `WARN` or `DEBUG` details doesnt show  in the log file as well as console out put.But i want to log every details in to log file including `INFO`.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs:

> Assuming the configuration files logback-test.xml or logback.xml are
>   not present, logback will default to invoking BasicConfigurator which
>   will set up a minimal configuration. This minimal configuration
>   consists of a ConsoleAppender attached to the root logger.

If you want to disable all console output, you should try removing the default ConsoleAppender.  According to the [BasicConfigurator source](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/BasicConfigurator.html), this appender's name is "console".  So you could try (untested):

```
logger.detachAppender("console");
```

I highly recommend moving these programmatic configurations into a logback.xml file, and only changing the configuration programmatically when necessary.  The config file is more explicit and easier to manage in my opinion.

Comment: this didn't work.as a temporary solution i added a dummy `lockback.xml` file into my project and overwrite default behavior.My logback xml contails only following xml tag only `<configuration></configuration>` this is not the elegant way to do but it did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
logger.setAdditivity(false);
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether the above was ever correct or whether maybe it changed since the answer was given, but I ran into this today, and as of Logback version 1.2.3 at least, the correct form is `logger.setAdditive(false);` (and it worked for me as well)

Comment: This worked for me as well.
`logger.setAdditive(false);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by removing the `ConsoleAppenderfrom`your logback configuration.

the log back config will be as follows.

```
<configuration>

<appender name="logFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
<file>c:/logs/serverlog.log</file>
<append>true</append>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
 <appender-ref ref="logFileAppender" />
</root>

</configuration>
```