# printing test container stdout into a file

Tags: stdout, slf4j, testcontainers

I am using test container in my project. I am getting stdout in console of each container by using:

```
container.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger("container"))))
```

and i am getting output something like this:

```
[docker-java-stream--1578738495] INFO container - STDOUT:   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
[docker-java-stream--1578738495] INFO container - STDOUT:   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
[docker-java-stream--1578738495] INFO container - STDOUT:   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
[docker-java-stream--1578738495] INFO container - STDOUT:   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

but i am trying to add stdout into a separate file. I was trying something like this but it's not working.

```
            PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("file.txt"));
            PrintStream console = System.out;
            System.setOut(o);
            System.out.println((container.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger("container")))));
            System.setOut(console);
```

I cannot use log4j because  this project will be used as a dependency into another project and log4j might create conflict so i need some solution to print stdout into a file if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Slf4j `Logger` as the parameter of the `Slf4jConsumer` constructor, for example, a logger that writes to a file:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);

// create fileAppender
// ...
logger.addAppender(fileAppender);

Slf4jLogConsumer logConsumer = new Slf4jLogConsumer(LOGGER);
container.followOutput(logConsumer);
```

You can find more information regarding the programmatic configuration of Slf4j loggers and appenders in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215011/1396362) SO answer.